# How should I reconnect my ceiling fan to this three-way circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, multiway-switch

[image][image]I am replacing a kitchen ceiling light/fan in a house I just recently purchased. It has two separate cables coming into it. Each contains a red, black, white, and ground wire.

The box is controlled by two switches that are at opposite sides of the kitchen.

The fan kit has a black white blue and ground wire.

Unfortunately I didn’t pay attention how it was wired prior when tearing out the old fan.

[image]

Comment: With the breaker still off, open up the switches and take pictures, so we can see how the switches are wired.  Were those wires connected like that before?

Comment: I will send pictures  if the switches when I’m off shift. 

But yes that’s how it was wired when I pulled the fan down and finally looked at the wires

Comment: Two single pole switches? Do you mean that both switches must be off to turn off the fan?

Comment: whenever i see this type of questions i always wonder; wouldn't it be faster to just meter all 4 permutations than to write up a question and wait around for answers?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a switch leg to me.
The black and white connected.

This takes the power down to the switch on the white as hot all the time.

Jumper that white to 2 switches then you can bring back the power on the black for 1 switch

The second switch is on the red wire.

Connecting devices at the fixture is the red or white to the fan and the other to a light. This is an inexpensive way to provide for 2 devices with 1 cable.

Unfortunately code outdated this application in the last update as on newer homes a neutral is required in 1 switch box (in the case of a 3 way one side requires a neutral).

But this is what I think you have from the 2 switch comment and what I see at the fixture.

Comment: So where would I connect the black white and blue wire from the fan kit